# Delete records when a field is updated

Tags: apex, trigger

I am having a condition where we are having a field called number of employees in Account object and we have to create same number of contacts associated with the perticular account.

And If we update the field "Number of employee" it will add or delete those number of contact records in the account.
For Example :- We were having 5 number of employee in the field (5 contacts), and we update it to 5 --> 7 so it should add 2 (7-5) more contact in the particular account. And if we update it to 5--> 2, it should delete 3 (5-2) contact records from the account.

```java
if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
        List<Contact> connList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account acc:trigger.new){
            if(trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).NumberOfEmployees != trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).NumberOfEmployees){
                for(Integer i=trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).NumberOfEmployees; i<trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).NumberOfEmployees; i++){
                    Contact con = new Contact();
                    con.FirstName = 'Fname'+i;                
                    con.LastName = 'Lname'+i;
                    con.AccountId = acc.Id;
                    connList.add(con);
                }
            }
        }
        insert connList;

//This is my aproach whenever we are updating from 5-->7 it will add 2 more contact records
```

I need help in whenever we are updating it from 5-->2, how can we delete that number of contact records from the Account.

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to get all the contacts, then loop through and add the extra contacts to another list, and then delete that list.

Comment: in the delete case - do you delete fifo or lifo or some other order?

Comment: I want to use lifo to delete the contact records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate on existing contacts and store number of contacts (Old Employees - New Employees) into a new list and delete them after iteration.